Issue with Changing @Table Annotation to "users" in JPA Entity Class Using H2 Database
I'm encountering an issue with my Java application where changing the @Table name in my entity class causes the application to fail during tests and runtime. Here are the details:
Originally, my entity class was defined as follows:
@ApiModel
@XStreamAlias("user")
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
// ...
}

The application worked fine with this setup. However, when I updated the @Table annotation to change the table name from "user" to "users", as shown below:
@ApiModel
@XStreamAlias("user")
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
// ...
}

I started getting errors when running mvn test and during application startup. The error message is:
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "USERS" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD CONSTRAINT USERS_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (SUBSCRIPTION_ID) REFERENCES SUBSCRIPTIONS (SUBSCRIPTIONID)  [42102-200]

Interestingly, if I revert the table name back to "user", everything works fine again. This makes me wonder if this issue is related to the H2 database I'm using for testing, or if there's something deeper causing this problem.
What could be causing this error? I even changed the table name in the JPA annotation to something else, and it worked fine. So why is the name "users" specifically causing an issue?

Also updated the H2 dependency to 2.3.230 still getting the same error

The issue with changing the table name from "user" to "users" in the Java entity class is likely due to case sensitivity or "users" being a reserved keyword in the H2 database used for testing.
To fix this, add a property in the persistence.xml configuration file to handle case sensitivity explicitly. Here's the simplified solution:
 @Entity
-@Table(name = "user")
+@Table(name = "users")
 public class User {
     @Id

In the persistence.xml, add the following property:
<property name="datanucleus.identifier.case" value="MixedCase"/>

This property ensures that table names are treated exactly as written in the annotations, resolving any case sensitivity issues.
